# Close executor app by executed app

Tags: c#

I have got a problem with my C# project. I got there 2 applications:

- Executor application which I will call Mini Launcher
- Executed application which I will call Launcher

My problem is: I want to run my Launcher by Mini launcher and in on Show event of Launcher app close Mini Launcher. 
My Mini Launcher is something like splash screen but with additional functionality like upgrade Launcher, and other. Its my execution code:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "My Directory"
startInfo.FileName = "My App";
try
{
    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
    {
        exeProcess.();
    }
}
catch
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: How are you launching the second app from the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. Named mutices provide a way for applications to send signals to one another. 
The following sample shows two Console-applications. The TestMutexLauncher-application launches the TestMutex application:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestMutexLauncher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p = Process.Start("TestMutex");
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for other process to release the mutex.");
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // maybe p.WaitForInputIdle is an alternative for WinForms/WPF
            Mutex mutex = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                if (Mutex.TryOpenExisting("MyUniqueMutexName", out mutex))
                    break;
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            if (mutex != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    mutex.WaitOne();
                    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                }
                finally
                {
                    mutex.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The launcher application starts the process and waits for a Mutex to be created in the other process. If it can acquire ownership of the the Mutex in a specified time frame, it waits to get ownership of the Mutex. After that, it realeases and disposes the Mutex.
The first task of the launched application is to create the Mutex, do the initialization actions and then release the Mutex.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace TestMutex
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var mutex = new Mutex(true, "MyUniqueMutexName"))
            {
                // Do something
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                    Console.Write(".");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Press enter...");
                Console.ReadLine();
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                Console.Write(".");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter...");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could You give me an example please?

Comment: @ArturSzymański: I've edited my answer and provided a sample.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would recommend you consider:

1) Do they actually need to be separate applications?

2) If so, why can't MiniLauncher just close itself after Launcher has loaded?

But if you have to do it this way, then the code you're looking for is something like this:

```
private void OnShow()
{
    var target = Process.GetProcessesByName("MiniLauncher.exe").FirstOrDefault();

    if (target != null)
    {
        // any other checks that this is indeed the process you're looking for
        target.Close();
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. My Mini Launcher must be another application because MiniLauncher will change files of Launcher when its needed.

Comment: 2. Initialize time of my Launcher app will last few seconds and user have to know about something that happens currently.

Comment: 3. Its good idea but there is a situation where user have got an application which block access to process tree and it will not work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

you can call another project executable from current running project and then you can close your application.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
        //
        // Open the application "application" that is in the same directory as
        // your .exe file you are running.
        //
        Process.Start("example.txt");
// or for another directory you need to specify full path 
Process.Start("C:\\");
        }
    }
```